# Unable to obtain Jdbc connection from DataSource - Flyway

Tags: spring, flyway

I have a MariaDB database running as a docker container the database is available on: `127.0.0.1:3306` and no application has any problems connecting to the database with the given credentials.

MySQL Workbench (no issues), DataGrip (no issues), Artisan (no issues), IDEA IDE Database view (no issues), manual connection (no issues). No issues at all the service is available at localhost on default port and all other applications can connect to them with no problem.

However `flyway` will throw:

```
Flyway 4.1.1 by Boxfuse

ERROR:
Unable to obtain Jdbc connection from DataSource (jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/local_db_emp) for user 'local_user_emp': Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:3306: unexpected end of stream, read 0 bytes from 4
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 08
Error Code : -1
Message    : Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:3306: unexpected end of stream, read 0 bytes from 4
```

This is how I'm running the `flyway` command:

```
flyway \
    -driver=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver \
    -url=jdbc:mariadb://127.0.0.1:3306/local_db_emp \
    -user=local_user_emp \
    -password=local_pass_emp \
    -locations=filesystem:/src/main/resources/migrations \
    -sqlMigrationPrefix= \
    migrate
```

I have also tried:
- using `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`
- using `jdbc:mysql`
- using MySQL driver
- tried using docker container name `dev_database` instead of `127.0.0.1 || localhost`

Pinged the service and no issues available everywhere just not with `flywayz.

Comment: Confirmed that `org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver` works as a JDBC driver *and* it is the driver from the classpath that is being used?

Comment: Can you run a quick experiment and let us know the results if you point to a non listening port. Do you get the same error dialog back?

Comment: @markdsievers Sorry I have been absent. Running lsof shows the database service listening for connections. Attempting to connect to the service using any other app/lib works without any issue. What I did is instead of CLI I used the Flyway java lib and it worked without any issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem and realized had  made a mistake on the config folder for flyway..

Make sure your connection database name has been uncommented before you can add your local url ..the doc comes commented so i forgot to uncomment and which prevented flyway to connect with my SQL database or recognize it.

flyway.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost
In order to use location you will have to make sure its not commented.

see example bellow

"#"flyway.user=Pink

flyway.user= pink

I had to do the same thing for the jdbc connection and password.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm calling the command directly without config file but I did also try the config file approach and still same issue I checked the properties 5 times.

Comment: Sorry to hear that.Do you happen to have the error..or something you see on your console.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using powershell may be it would make a difference.